# Undefined index: custom_css

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress 3.8.1

When I do a backup I set it to send it to my email. Nothing has changed in the site and the last successful backup was 3/6/14. I don't receive the email and I get the error bolded below. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

~Joe

Progress

DO NOT DO THE FOLLOWING AS IT WILL CAUSE YOUR BACKUP TO FAIL:

Close this browser
Reload this page
Click the Stop or Back buttons in your browser

Progress:
100%
The following errors were reported: Undefined index: custom_css

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by setting the `WP_DEBUG` option in your `wp-config.php` file to `true`, or, more general - setting some `PHP` variable to be more error responsive, for example `error_reporting(~E_ALL)`.

Check those variables on both places (`wp-config.php` and `php.ini`). Remember to disable verboseness in your production environment. If the cause is the latter, then your hosting provider has updated their server(s) and configuration files. Otherwise someone has messed up with your `wp-config.php` file, because the error *Undefined index:* is shown **only when verboseness is set to maximum**.

However is good programming practice to initialize variables before usage in your scripts (`Undefined index:` means exactly that variable is not set/initialized before usage).

Comment: I do know that custom_css is a plugin I had installed and then removed.  I'm wondering if it left its footprints in other places and didn't do a clean uninstall

Comment: If you removed it from Wordpess uninstall option (not directly deleting the folder via ftp) there is no way files of the plugin to be left over.